# How to ping IP Address form .txt in Python

Tags: python, ip

How to coding for ping address from textfile(.txt) in D:
I'm currently using python 3.1 and will need to ping multi ip address in text file

*** Feel free to suggest coding.

```
import requests
import os

def notifyNetwork(message):
    token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    uri = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify"
    header = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
    msg = {"message": "TEST \n" + message}
    resp = requests.post(uri, headers=header, data=msg)

hostname = list([['192.168.1.200','EU (SERVER)', True]])

def checkNetwork(hostname):
    response = os.system("ping "+hostname)
    print(response)
    if (response==1):
        status = False
    else:
        status = True
    return status

while True:
    for index, TEST in enumerate(hostname):
        currentStatus = checkNetwork(TEST[0])
        previusStatus = TEST[2]
        if currentStatus == previusStatus:
            print('-----No Notify-----')
        else:
            hostname[index][2] = currentStatus
            if currentStatus:
                statusNetwork = 'UP'
            else:
                statusNetwork = 'Down'
            message = f"IP : {hostname[index][0]}\nName : {hostname[index][1]}\n{statusNetwork}"
            notifyNetwork(message)
            print('---- Notify ----')
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(5)
    print(hostname)
```

Comment: `status = response != 1` `for host in hostname:` and `ip, name, _ = host`  `host[2] = currentStatus` `checkNetwork(ip)` `previusStatus = host[2]`

Comment: ever wondered to look how to open a file in python and iterate over the lines, and then parse a line based on a separator character/string

Comment: why do you sleep 5 sec after each host check

Comment: don't hard code the path to the file with IP addresses, use a script argument `sys.argv`

Comment: @DarkZone Do you still need help or is this resolved for you?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the motivation behind reading from (or writing to) the file is being able to terminate the process and re-run it later, keeping status.

Let's first propose a format for the file. Each line in the file will represent a server. Keep in mind that the server-name can't contain semicolon `;`, as that is used as separator. last-status is either "UP" or "Down".

```
<IP-address>;<server-name>;<last-status>
```

At the beggining define servers to be checked in the file.
Then read the file line by line, checking the status and save it to a new temporary file. After you've read all lines, replace the old file with the temporary file, effectively updating its contents.

```py
import requests
import os

def notifyNetwork(message):
    pass  # You can keep this function as is.

# Removed the 'hostname' variable, as those values will be read from a file.

def checkNetwork(hostname):
    pass  # You can keep this function as is.

status_file = "the-file.txt"
tmp_file = "tmp.txt"

while True:
    with open(status_file, "r") as host_states, open(tmp_file, "w") as tmp:
        for line in host_states:  # read the file line by line.
            # rstrip() removes '\n' and whitespaces
            ip, name, previusStatus = line.rstrip().split(";")
            print(f"{ip=}, {name=}, {previousStatus=}")
            assert previousStatus in ["UP", "Down"]

            currentStatus = checkNetwork(ip)
            if currentStatus:
                statusNetwork = 'UP'
            else:
                statusNetwork = 'Down'

            if statusNetwork == previusStatus:
                print('-----No Notify-----')
            else:
                message = f"IP : {ip}\nName : {name}\n{statusNetwork}"
                notifyNetwork(message)
                print('---- Notify ----')

            # Save the current status to temp file.
            tmp.write(f"{ip};{name};{statusNetwork}\n")

        # I don't know what next line was supposed to do. Commenting it out.
        # schedule.run_pending()

    # Now replace the old file with the tmp.txt.
    os.replace(tmp_file, status_file)

    time.sleep(5)
```